# Global Parameters config in yaml config file

Tags: java, ruby, spring

I am trying to set up global parameters in yaml file that I can use in my code.

For example in my dev.yaml I have

```
globalParameters:
 baseUrl: https://beta.example.com
```

The idea is to add additional parameters and urls under globalParameters. I already figured out how to use those values with

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "globalParameters")
```

But I am not able to set the globalParameters scheme in application.yaml file which currently looks like that:

```
globalParameters:
 parameter: <%= parameter %>
```

The goal is to access with globalParameters with different parameters and get the corresponding value - in this case the url string. I get ruby exception for the bindings

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default) @  ---
(erb):48:in `get_binding': undefined local variable or method `baseUrl'
```

Comment: What sort of exception?

Comment: @KimmoLehto I updated the question with the exception

Comment: You used the `java` and `ruby` tags. What language do you actually use?